# does AWS Route 53 have a service like DynDNS or No-IP?

Tags: dns, amazon-web-services, dynamic-dns

I do local dev on an application that Twilio occasionally needs to make HTTP requests to. To facilitate this I have local.mydomain.com pointing to my computers IP address as it resolves to the outside world. The problem is...  that IP address changes when I'm in the office vs when I'm at home. And if I'm on the road it changes every time I get a different hotel.

Does AWS Route 53 have any functionality that could be used to remedy this problem or is my only solution to pay for a third party service like DynDNS or No-IP?

Comment: You'd need to ask Amazon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't have it natively. You can create a Lambda function which updates the IPs periodically

Answer (score -1):

I would edit my PCs hosts file so that a specific domain resolves to 127.0.0.1 / localhost. A hosts file is basically hard coded local DNS.

You can search for more details of where the hosts file is and the format based on the OS you're using.

Here's an example of what I might do if I had a web server running on port 80 that I wanted to address by domain name

```
127.0.0.1       localhost local.example.com my.development.com
```